# Binding layer display in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, layers

I work on several layers in arcmap 9.3.

My question is about creating binds to display theses layers directly.
like

```
ctrl+1 ( display / hide  layer 1 )
ctrl+2 ( display / hide  layer 2 )
ctrl+3 ( display / hide  layer 3 )
ctrl+4 ( display / hide  layer 4 )
```

I Didn't find it in the keyboard menu.

Is there a way of doing it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "display these layers directly"? Do you want them to be the only visible layer when hitting a given shortcut? Or do you want to open the layer's properties dialog?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot imagine this being an out-of-box option within the application.  In 10.2, you may assign shortcut to turn on/off all layers in the TOC, but not specific to certain layer names.  Most likely you will have to develop either VBA or .net function using arcobjects that calls a command on keyboard shortcut (to turn x layer on or off).

[Assign Shortcut Key to Command Snippet](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0049000000qz000000)

Answer (score 0):

The options for creating shortcut keys at ArcGIS 9.3 are described in its **[Online Help](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Creating_shortcut_keys)**.  If what you want is not possible at that version then I would expect that it is at 10.1.